# Overriding TestSetting Parameters with *.RunSettings in VSTS build with SpecRun

Tags: specflow, azure-pipelines, vstest, specrun

Just been googling around and found , parameters can't be overridden with SpecRun in VSTS build's VSTest task when using *.RunSettings. Just wondering if anyone has successfully does it before?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the content of the file before running test, for example, using Tokenization task to modify file.

[Using Tokenization (Token Replacement) for Builds/Releases in vNext/TFS 2015](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)

On the other hand, there is a thread about reading parameter value in specflow test: [How to read test run settings parameter value in specflow tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791016/how-to-read-test-run-settings-parameter-value-in-specflow-tests)?