# Runsetting file NOT WORKING with SpecFlow+MSTest+SpecRun.Specflow

Tags: .net-core, mstest, specflow, specrun, runsettings

I checked almost all stack overflow and Microsoft documentation on how to read parameters from .runsettings file in MSTest and tried all the approaches but none worked for me.

`I am using .NETCore 2.2, VS 2019, Selenium, SpecFlow+ Runner.`

**Does not Work with SpecRun.SpecFlow nuget Package but works with SpecFlow.MStest nuget package.**

I tried to use it as mentioned here:

1. [How to read test run settings parameter value in specflow tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791016/how-to-read-test-run-settings-parameter-value-in-specflow-tests)
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019
3. [How to access TestRunParameters within RunSettings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707415/how-to-access-testrunparameters-within-runsettings-file)

None of them worked for me.

`.runsettings file:`

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="appUrl" value="http://example.com" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

I tried to get "appUrl":

`public TestContext context {get;set;};`

```
 [ClassInitialize]
    public static void TestClassinitialize(TestContext context)
    {
      var webAppUrl = context.Properties["appUrl"].ToString();
    }
```

I tried `[AssemblyIntilize]` / `[TestInitialize]` as well.

I don't know if MSTest supports this with SpecFlow+ Runner.
Please help.

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: I edited your title editt. It's inappropriate and unnecessary to add REOPENED to the title. It's clear it got reopened because it no longer says [ON HOLD] or [CLOSED]. Please don't add noise and clutter that isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an `Open Issue:`

**https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/817**

Have to wait.

Comment: Correct. MSTest's RunSettings parameters (and other MSTest values) can only be accessed within classes or methods that are decorated with the `TestClass` or `TestMethod` attributes.

Comment: @natn2323 - It is not working when I am using `SpecRun.SpecFlow  nuget package` as mentioned here: `https://specflow.org/getting-started/`